# Извлечь степень php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Не пойму, как извлечь степень, чтоб число 1000 выводило 3, т.к. это 10 в 3 степени. Или число 10000 выводило 4, т.к. это 10 в 4 степени. Или любое другое число, не обязательно только 10-ку гонять.

Comment: с помощью `pow()` ?)

Comment: `число 10000 выводило 4, т.к. это 10 в 4 степени` - почему вы решили что 10000 — это 10 в 4, а не 100 во 2, к примеру?  или например 256 - это 16 в квадрате или 2  в восьмой или 4 в четвертой?

Comment: pow — возводит в степень, а мне нужно обратное действие.

Comment: Алексей, тут вот какая штука, есть к примеру число 1000, и знашь что есть число к примеру 10, вот нужно получить степень, основываясь на эти два параметра

Comment: @dgdhsk исправьте вопрос чтобы он соответсовал тому что действительно вам нужно. Вам нужно не извлечь корень, а найти степень в которой есть это число. Судя из вашего комментария.

Comment: @dgdhsk а, ну тогда всё проще... хотя вон смотрю в ответах уже написали что как.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вам известно и число, которое возводится в степень и итоговое число, являющееся результатом возведения исходного числа, то нужно использовать логарифм. Если конкретно,то [log](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.log.php)

Например:

```
$val = 10000;
echo log($val, 10); // выведет 4
```

10 основание, $val (10000) - результат возведения в степень.

Comment: вот это и искал, большое спасибо

Answer (score 6):

Из курса математики все помнят что корень - есть ничто иное как степень числа. А значит можно использовать функцию `pow()`.
К примеру кубический корень из 1000 можно записать как 1000 в степени 1/3 - `pow(1000, 1/3);`

Если же вам надо найти степень числа - эта операция нахождения логарифма числа. Опять таки, как мы знаем из курса математики. В пхп можно найти с помощью - `log(1000, 10);` Где первый аргумент ваше число, второй основание.

Comment: _В PHP 5.6 и выше вы можете использовать оператор **_. ©